# There is not even a single thing

Tags: grammar, articles, adverbs

> There is not even **a single thing** in the shop.

The article **a** and **single** means one. Can we use these two together?

Is the sentence is correct if we remove the article **a** or the word **single**? (ie, There is not even  **single** thing.....)

Is the article **a** is for the noun **thing**?

Is the word **even** acting as an adverb? If it is an adverb,which verb is it defining?

Comment: Hey jbn, you've asked 5 questions. The standard here is to ask just one at a time. If you need to ask all 5 questions, consider posting 5 separate questions. Also, please include what you've considered already and what research you've done yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word **thing** is countable, so it always needs an article (*a* thing, *the* thing) or a determiner (*my* thing, *John's* thing, etc.)  Therefore the sentence is incorrect if you try to remove the article, like

> There is not even single thing...

because *single* is an adjective, not a determiner.  You could remove the adjective *single* and make it

> There is not even a thing...

although it is more fluent to say

> There is not a thing...

if you mean there is nothing at all.

**Even** is an adverb; the definition in this case is

> [used as an intensive to stress an extreme or highly unlikely condition or instance](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/even)

Since there is only one verb in the sentence ("is"), it's modifying that one.